# How to hook LCD to breadboard using T cobbler?

Tags: gpio, pitft, breadboard

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here:

[image]

Now I am a newb and I have watched 5-7 intro videos about the cobbler and breadboard, but they are always doing LEDs. I was under the impression that this cobbler just makes it easy to see/plug/test things out before committing to soldering. I was trying to plug this in the same as I would to the actual pins on the Pi.

I'm connecting the pins that the schematics of the LCD show are necessary (excluding the pins that control touch functions).  As you can see, I have at least hooked up all the power and ground connections, but there is no power to the screen.

I think I need to add jumpers from the pins I'm using to the ground (except for the gnd pins)?  I am just not sure and wanted to get some expert help/advice before going further.

Here is a link for the LCD (has pin designations):
https://www.waveshare.com/3.5inch-rpi-lcd-a.htm

Also, this does power on fine when plugged directly into the Pi.

Comment: Can you measure 3V3 and 5V on the breadboard?  A common error is to have the ribbon cable plugged in the wrong way around at one end.

Comment: I agree, but this is the only way the power LED on the cobbler comes on, so assuming I have it installed correctly.  When I swap it around, the LED doesn't come on. I am actually grateful for that power LED, lol.  I noticed not all cobblers have one.

Comment: Cobbler does just make testing things simpler. What is the specification / wiring requirement of your LCD screen - have you got a link ?

Comment: @CoderMike I have added the link to the question :)

Comment: Yes I am using the same power supply that I use when connecting the LCD directly, and it powers on when being connected directly. To clarify it is 5V/2A.  The power supply is half shown on the picture, but was made specifically for the pi.

Comment: It does at least appear that I do not need to add jumpers.  Which does make me feel slightly better in my ignorance.  Also tonight I will try to get the female to female jumpers and plug directly into the cobbler eliminating the breadboard as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to update this and close it as solved.  While the pi was connected to the breadboard properly, I had the pins on the opposite sides on the actual LCD. Once I swapped the sides it powered on and displayed properly. Thanks for all the help, as a newb it helped me to debug the issue.